# controlling a svg image fill color

Tags: css, html, svg

I have this `svg` image that I want to change the colour of, however I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
<svg width="20" height="20" fill="#FFF">
    <image xlink:href="images/person.svg" fill="#FFF" width="20" height="20" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You can't...it's an ***image*** not a SVG element like a polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the SVG 1.1 spec:

> The result of processing an ‘image’ is always a four-channel RGBA
>   result.

In other words, the SVG is rendered as a bitmap.  And you can't change the colour of a bitmap with `fill`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Is there any way I can change the colour of my svg file at all?

Comment: you can crack open the file and change it inside the file, or you can use a filter with feColorMatrix to recolor it